# Gigabyte aivia k8100 v2 - Keys seem to get stuck sometimes

Tags: keyboard

I have a very random bug with my gaming keyboard. It sometimes acts like a key is pressed  continuously but in reality it isn't. The keys also don't seem to get stuck but I still get this problem.

So for instance, if I try to type this sentence: "Hello, how are you doing?"
This is the result that I actually get: "Hello, how arrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"

It's very random and as far as I know it can happen to all of my keys. I do have 1 suspicion and that is the anti-ghosting software. I'm not a keyboard expert but it might be a bug from that software.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the keyboard interior?

Comment: No I haven't because my keyboard is actually pretty clean. But I'll have a look just in case.

Comment: The keyboard interior can be grimy even if the outside is clean. It's definitely something to try; while I'm not familiar with your particular model, I do know that dirty contacts can cause all kinds of weird behavior in keyboards.